# What is the name of this greenish plant?

Tags: leaf-vegetables, ornamental-plant

Hello i have this plant with green leafs it has some yellow flowers but i don't know its name can you tell me what is the name of this plant?[image]

Flower image
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

After searching so much finally i found that it is Turnera ulmifolia

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it could be [Lamium galeobdolon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lamium%20galeobdolon%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjV6qrUxcrpAhVJrhoKHUgwBigQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22lamium%20galeobdolon%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIABAYUNUuWI87YN5AaABwAHgAgAFBiAGwA5IBATiYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=7mHJXtW7A8ncasjgmMAC&bih=625&biw=1366&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB725GB725)? Not all are variegated.

Comment: The flowers of lamium galeobdolon looks different

Comment: @user3110224 - Very different. The original photo didn't include flowers :-)

Comment: Ok got it but now uploaded the pic of flowers as well.

Comment: I asked to the gardener and he said it has daily flowers but this plant does not produce seeds